# Accidentally shared personal information via screenshot. How to delete from stack.imgur.com?

Tags: support

I uploaded a screenshot to ServerFault, or more precisely, to stack.imgur.com. The screenshot contained personal information, which I only discovered afterwards.

I replaced the screenshot in the answer, but I want to delete the very image from stack.imgur.com. How would I do that?

Comment: Is it worth migrating this to meta.SE so it can be closed as a duplicate there?

Comment: In case it makes you feel any better, I have seen a user do much worse than that: Post a question on [security.se] asking something along the lines of "has my server been hacked?" Include a screenshot of a terminal session with said server - using a transparent terminal - placed in front of a spreadsheet - containing all his passwords neatly arranged in three columns with user name, password, and site name - and he did not even realize what he had just done.

Comment: No way that was not first class trolling! And hilarious as well!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [Contact Us](https://meta.serverfault.com/contact) form at the bottom of the page (select Other), and give us the link to whichever images you want removed. We will take care of it from there (assuming you uploaded them through this site, we can't remove them from normal imgur, just stack.imgur -- doesn't look like that should be a problem in this case).

(Here is a link to the [canonical post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202717/how-can-i-remove-an-image-from-imgur/202719#202719))